# An accidental friendship

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

When our family moved to a new house, we got familiar with our neighbors Mr. and Mrs. Watson. They invited us for dinner that night and wanted us to be their guests. My parents agreed and we were together all that night. After the dinner, a couple who were their relatives came to them. They had a little daughter in my age. We couldn't get familiar with each other, because we were short of time and we had to leave.

That's unsurprising that after that night, we never meet each other. My middle school ended and I went to a higher class in high school. When I entered to the area of the school, suddenly met someone whose face rang a bell. I focused on her face and...

That was the girl that I met that night!

I remember first meeting her in high school. We approached each other and after greetings sat close to each other and started talking to each other.

We both had an interest in the arts and theatre. We actually had a class together, even though she is a year older than me. This was totally a God-oriented placing because otherwise, we never may have met or been as close!

Regarding the type of the friendship mentioned in the made-up story above, we have a sentence in our language. We say:

> 1. Our friendship was quite accidental.

Or

> 2. We made friends quite accidentally.

Do the above sentences make sense in English?
If not, please let me know how would you imply this message in natural English?

Thank you.

Comment: +1 for the conrext and the love story :) Hmm, what about the dear "accident"? It was an accident! Anyways, didn't know there's a world as "God-oriented". Good!

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking specifically about a friendship with one person (the girl) I think it would be better to use 1. This is because it implies a friendship between two people, or two groups of people with each other.

Option 2, in my opinion, would imply "we" as a group made friends with this person or group of people. I would use option two if you were saying your family, or you and your brother, made friends with the girl.

I think both are correct though.

Hope that helps! Good story :)

Comment: I respectfully disagree @Bee. Because a pronoun like "we" cannot cause such a big difference, while the context or the conversation would imply your intention.

Comment: As i mentioned I think both are correct, I personally would use them in the context I outlined above. You're correct that the context of the rest of the story gives both a clear meaning.

Comment: +1 I completely agree with the first statement being more natural in terms of *what happened*. However, the second would be more appropriate in terms of describing an aspect of their personalities—a habitual statement that *used* to be true rather than the mention of a past event. (They were the kind of people who quite often developed accidental friendships.)